# how to add pgrouting on postgresql-9.3 on ubuntu 12.04LTS Precise

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, openstreetmap, postgis, pgrouting

I am newcomer and want to discover pgrouting.

I've already installed postgresql-9.3 and the postgis 2.1 extension on my laptop which runs ubuntu 12.04 Lts precise.

I don't want to have  to re-install postgresql.

Now I want to add the pgrouting extension to be able to create routing databases as indicated on the pgroutingworkshop tutorial. But they used postgresql-8 inside.

Comment: Is there a particular step in the instructions that is not working for you because of the newer postgres version?

Answer (score 1):

You need to your this tutorial: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/

Comment: I agree with Stephen's answer. I have pgrouting running on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit (PostgreSQL 9.1 and postGIS 2.0 from UbuntuGIS repo)

Comment: I have read it before to put my question, please. They don't mention anywhere how to do for my case.

Comment: The answer to your question is that you can not use the tutorial that you are trying to use based on pg 8.4 and on pg 9.x. You have to use the workshop tutorial that I linked to. Also I will note that I do not think postgis 2.0 works with pg 9.3, I think you must use postgis 2.1.

Comment: My configuration is: (Postgresql-9.3 and Postgis-2.1).               Now I want to add the Pgrouting-2.0 extension under my Postgresql-9.3, but the package postgresql-9.3-pgrouting or as other with dijkstra algorithms doesn't exist in my synaptic packets. How must I do please? If I must compile from sources, how should I proceed?

Comment: Even following your link http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/installation.html , they don't describe how to fix my problem, for those who use higher version of postgresql-9.1, like postgresql-9.3. Which package should I install at the place of postgresql-9.1-pgrouting?

Comment: I having the same issue and I get an ```E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.3-pgrouting``` error

Answer (score 1):

You should probably make sure you are fetching packages from https://launchpad.net/~georepublic/+archive/pgrouting This is the packages maintained by Georeublic and they are one of the development teams working on pgRouting along with iMaptools.